# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(ConnectedRouterWithContext)" with react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Here is my **index.js**

```
const customContext = React.createContext(context)
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history} context={customContext}>
      <Route render={() => <App context={customContext} />} />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('react-root')
);
```

And my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route render={()=> "text"}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )

const mapStateToProps = {};
const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

I get the following error as is:

```
 Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(ConnectedRouterWithContext)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(ConnectedRouterWithContext) in connect options.
    at invariant (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/invariant/browser.js:38:15)
```

I am using

```
 "connected-react-router": "^6.8.0",
    "react-redux": "7.0.1",
    "react-router": "5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0"
```

**Things I have tried**

I have tried adding `context={customContext}` to be `Provider store={store} context={customContext}`
But then I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of null
```

I have also tried connecting the context in App.js, I have tried older versions of react-redux, ie: react-redux 6.0.0. and I get a different error with that one. Looking for debugging assistance since every example I find using react redux with react router and connected react router doesn't seem to work.

ps. I've stripped out a lot of code to simplify. It would be easier to re-write everything but i'm not quite there yet.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this was broken from the first place is that I used to be passing my context object directly into

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Route render={() => <App context={context} />} />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
```

But apparantly either the new react router or conntected router reserves the context word. Just changing context name to a different property name fixed everything.